pandas populating a DataFrame from a data table
I have two data frames where I would like to populate one with the others data. Both use the same indexes, just oriented differently. The second array is not a simple pivot though as the indexes are selected for some analysis down the road.
I have a solution below. It is very simple but it uses a for loop which might not be the most efficient. Is there a way to populate the second table without using a loop?
data structure for visualization
  a    b    c                             values
a .    .    .                    a    d    .
b .    .    .                         g    .
c .    .    .                    b    h    .
d .    .    .                    c    e    .
e .    .    .                         d    .
f .    .    .            -->          j    .
g .    .    .
h .    .    .
i .    .    .
j .    .    .

simple code to do the above
np.random.seed(0) # for reproducibility
test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3), index=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"], columns=["a","b","c"])
new_array = pd.DataFrame({"t1":["a","a","b","c","c","c"],"t2":["d","g","h","e","d","j"], "value":[np.nan, np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]})
new_array = new_array.set_index(["t1", "t2"])
for indexes in new_array.index:
    new_array.loc[indexes, "value"] = test.loc[indexes[1], indexes[0]]


You could unstack, convert to_frame and reindex_like:
new_array = test.unstack().to_frame(name='value').reindex_like(new_array)

Or to modify in place:
new_array['value'] = test.unstack()

Output:
          value
t1 t2          
a  d   0.383442
   g   0.778157
b  h   0.461479
c  e   0.071036
   d   0.528895
   j   0.414662


Another possible solution, which follows the OP's approach and uses stack:
new_array.assign(value = test.stack().loc[zip(t2, t1)].values)

Output:
          value
t1 t2          
a  d   0.383442
   g   0.778157
b  h   0.461479
c  e   0.071036
   d   0.528895
   j   0.414662

